# Trigger reset does not clear all inputs

Tags: jquery

I need to clear all the inputs inside form But when I execute  trigger reset function. It clears text fields but not the  textarea fields

```html
<form id="frm" action="">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input name="" type="text" placeholder="Alan Adını Giriniz" value="" class="form-control" id="txtCokluDomain">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><input type="button" id="liteyeEkle" class="btn btn-success" value="Ekle">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4  ">
      <textarea name="" id="textAreaDomainListesi" cols="35" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Where is your code which triggers the reset?

Comment: here     $('#frm').trigger("reset")

Comment: Ok, and how do you call that? Please edit the question to include all the relevant JS

Comment: I tried your same code, the text area **is** being reset as well. Are you getting any errors in the console?

Answer (score -1):

Normally, text area can be reset by modifying the value to  ''

Assuming that you are calling the trigger() from a button click, add the below code after you call the trigger function:

```
$("#textAreaDomainListesi").val('');
```